# Actual IE6 Png fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, png

What png fix method is the most actual today? Lite-weight, with background-repeat and background-position support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create PNG's with Fireworks and encode them as PNG8 instead of PNG32.
See: http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2007/09/18/png8-the-clear-winner/

No need for js, no need for css filter.
Unless you need more then 256 colours, then you are stuck with filter/js fixes.

Comment: PNG8 requires a matte color, much like gifs.

Comment: danixd not with Fireworks, fireworks is special, read the article ;)

Answer (score 1):

[IE7.JS](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) in my view:

> IE7.js is a JavaScript library to make
>   Microsoft Internet Explorer behave
>   like a standards-compliant browser. It
>   fixes many HTML and CaSS issues and
>   makes transparent PNG work correctly
>   under IE5 and IE6.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the [DD_BelatedPNG](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/) method is superior to the filter method used by ie7.js.

> You can use PNGs as the SRC of an
>    element or as a
>   background-image property in CSS.
>
> If you attempt the latter, you will
>   find that, unlike with vanilla usage
>   of AlphaImageLoader,
>   background-position and
>   background-repeat work as intended.
>
> As a bonus, "fixed" elements will
>   respond to a commonly used set of
>   Javascript style assignments, as well
>   as the A:hover pseudo-class.